# Rails4.2上でAngular2を動かしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

現在↓の記事を参考にRails 4.2にAngularJS 1.5を載せています
http://blog.mah-lab.com/2014/11/17/angularjs-rails/

AngularJSであれば↓の記事のようにRails Assets を使って簡単にインストールできました
http://tnakamura.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/06/19/113000

Angular2も↑と同様にインストールできないでしょうか
npm や bower はなるべく使いたくないと考えています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2はbowerでの配布を行いません。Rails AssetsはBowerで配布されているパッケージを管理するツールなのでAngular 2はインストールできません。

Angular 2は現在npmでのパッケージ配布とビルド済みJavaScriptファイルの配布の2種類の配布形式を取っていますが、依存バージョンの管理なども含めnpmでのインストールを強く推奨します。